# Question about complex integration over half circle (not closed)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

Here we consider a complex function $f(z) = \frac{\sin(z)}{z-\alpha}$ where $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{2}+i \log(2)$.

I want to know $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-R}^{R}f(z)dz$ (let us call it $I$ for convenience).

Here is my solution so far:

(I got the residue of $f(z)$ in $z=\alpha$, which is $\frac{5}{4}$.)

Consider a positively oriented contour $\Gamma$ consisting of a line from $-R$ to $R$ (call it $\gamma_{-R,R}$) and an upper half circle with radius $R$ (call it $C_R^{+}$). Then, $$ 
\int_\Gamma f(z) dz = \int_{\gamma_{-R,R}}f(z)dz + \int_{C_R^{+}}f(z)dz.
$$
By Cauchy's residue theorem, $$
\int_\Gamma f(z) dz = 2\pi i\cdot Res(\alpha) = \frac{5\pi i}{2}.
$$
Hence, $$I = \frac{5\pi i}{2} - \lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{C_R^{+}}f(z)dz.$$

Here I stuck since I don't know how to find $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{C_R^{+}}f(z)dz$ which is integral over half circle (not closed).

Any helps or ideas (hints too) are more than welcome!

Comment: Consider $f_\pm(z)=e^{\pm iz}/(z-\alpha)$ instead of $f(z)$, integrated along $C_R^\pm$ respectively.

Comment: @metamorphy Ahh so I need to write $sin(z)$ from $f(z)$ into $(e^{it} - e^{-it})/2i$ form and use Jordon's lemma? Thanks! That really helps :)